# Big 5 personality traits means and SD

Tags: big-five

I'm looking for a fairly large (250+ people) study that gives the raw mean and sd of the 5 different big 5 personality traits (using whatever scale they choose in that paper) or just gives the raw data that I can use to calculate those values. I don't mind if it's split up into men and women as I already have data for the differences but I can't find any about the underlying distributions for each of the personality traits.

Thanks in advance, please ask if any clarifications are required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Means and SDs are going to vary based on the specific personality measure, the measurement context, and the sample.

Many of the thousands of journal articles that measure Big 5 personality will report descriptive statistics for their measure.

In terms of some available raw data for the Big Five.

Here is some based on IPIP data:
https://openpsychometrics.org/_rawdata/

Here are a bunch of repositories with Big 5 data:
https://osf.io/4mruh/
https://osf.io/4mruh/
https://osf.io/62gs7/
https://osf.io/cwbgv/
https://osf.io/daext/
https://osf.io/qjd48/files
https://osf.io/qk4r9/
https://osf.io/qk4r9/